# Securely remove file from ext3 linux

Tags: c, file, unix

This question has been asked with varying degrees of success in the past...

Are there tools, or C/C++ unix functions to call that would enable me to retrieve the location on disk of a file? Not some virtual address of the file, but the disk/sector/block the file resides in?

The goal here is to enable overwriting of the actual bits that exist on disk. I would probably need a way to bypass the kernel's superimposition of addresses. I am willing to consider an x86 asm based solution...

However, I feel there are tools that do this quite well already.

Thanks for any input on this.

Comment: Even though the question includes asking advice about programming API functions, the weight seems to be on tools, which is why I voted to move it to http://superuser.com/.

Comment: [shred](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shred+1) already does this, I believe.

Comment: This question becomes somewhat meaningless when you take into account the fact that data may have _no_ fixed location on some media, and that not all media have a notion of sector and block (the closest you could get to an universal location descriptor would be an offset in a one-dimensional bitstream). Now, if you are willing to limit the scope of your question to standard mechanical hard drives...

Comment: So this brings me to my next, and what seems like the more pressing question... How do tools like shred perform this task? Or do they lie?

Comment: For the sake of this discussion, lets assume the data sits on a "standard mechanical hard drive". Also... Maybe I am naive, but the data is always there...... It may be in multiple places, and it may be moving around to different places at arbitrary times, but it is still there, therefore it can be removed.

Comment: @Desh, did you read the `CAUTION` section in the man page I linked to?

Comment: @DeshBanks 'shred' simply assumes a mechanical hard disk drive in a standard system configuration (so no RAID or other features). It does not work on SSD's, for instance, and you cannot efficiently work around that at all in the case of an SSD because the extra indirection layer is located at the firmware level.

Answer (score 2):

Removing files securely is only possible under very specific circumstances:

- There are no uncontrolled layers of indirection between the OS and the actual storage medium.

  On modern systems that can no longer be assumed. SSD drives with firmware wear-leveling code do not work like this; they may move or copy data at will with no logging or possibility of outside control. Even magnetic disk drives will routinely leave existing data in sectors that have been remapped after a failure. Hybrid drives do both...

  The ATA specification does support a [SECURE ERASE](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) command which erases a whole drive, but I do not know how thorough the existing implementations are.
- The filesystem driver has a stable and unique mapping of files to physical blocks at all times.

  I believe that `ext2fs` does have this feature. I also think that `ext3fs` and `ext4fs` also work like this in the default journaling mode, but not when mounted with the `data=journal` option which allows for file data to be stored in the journal, rather than just metadata.

  On the other hand `reiserfs` definitely works differently, since it stores small amounts of data along with the metadata, unless mounted with the `notail` option.

If these two conditions are met, then a program such as [`shred`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shred) *may* be able to securely remove the content of a file by overwriting its  content multiple times.

This method still does not take into account:

- Backups
- Virtualized storage
- Left over data in the swap space
- ...

Bottom line:

- You can no longer assume that secure deletion is possible. Better assume that it is impossible and use encryption; you should probably be using it anyway if you are handling sensitive data.
- There is a reason that protocols regarding sensitive data mandate the physical destruction of the storage medium. There are companies that actually demagnetize their hard disk drives and then *shred* them before incinerating the remains...

Comment: Thank you for a very informative post. One way to 'securely' delete one file then may be to copy all known good files (except the target file) to an external disk, wipe the disk that contains the target file (write raw garbage to the entire thing), then move the files you copied off back onto the target disk... Assuming the target disk was entirely wiped, I feel this would work.

I definitely agree that using encryption when handling sensitive data is necessary. I am asking more out of curiosity than because I have an actual need to do this myself.

Comment: @DeshBanks: the method you propose would *probably* work, as long as your file has not happened to be in remapped sectors - in that case you would depend on ATA SECURE ERASE being thorough, which I would be reluctant to assume...